# React-select drop down obscured by active state of pagination

Tags: reactjs, react-select, reactstrap

- reactstrap version 5.0.0-alpha.4
- react version 16.1.1
- bootstrap version 4.0.0-alpha.6
- react-select 2.0.0-beta.2

I am using reactstrap with react-select. When I drop down a react-select item it appears below reactstrap's PaginationItem active state. All of the other elements appear below react-select's drop down. But I need to change the z-index of PaginationItem active. I am not sure how to write the css for this. Please point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the code you have written so far in the question, and preferably create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new).

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jj4n4wqxwy when you pull down the select component, you can see the 1 - active button is above it. I need it to be below.

Comment: You could set `z-index` to `0` on the active link. https://codesandbox.io/s/r59vxxlrjq

Comment: worked for me. Thanks for taking the time, add an answer I will accept. Can you like the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `z-index` to `0` on the active tab to make it appear behind the select dropdown.

```
<PaginationItem active style={{ zIndex: 0 }}>
  <PaginationLink>1</PaginationLink>
</PaginationItem>
```